# One main JS varibles file for multiple HTML files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am wanting to create one file where I can list and edit links without opening every file.

So I am wanting to have a page like http://example.com/links.js and in there I want to have all my information where I can information.

I will have around 20 http://example.com/link1.html etc. So instead of opening every HTML file to edit it, I would like to have just one main file where I can set for example links and titles.

I am not perfect at JS but I do understand the most parts. So in the jar file I will have like "var link1 = www.google.com" and inside link1.html, it will turn out as `<a href="www.google.com></a>` Something like that.

Sorry if you do not understand this as I am tired and cannot explain correctly. Thanks.

Comment: require editing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do this by using :)

```
link3 = function() {
location.href = "http://google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a broad topic but hopefully this will help you in designing your application.

You can have one js file will a json object. Example

**links.js**

```
var Links = {};  // namespacing

Links.linkObject = {
      linkOne:"someLink",
      linkTwo:"someLinkTwo",
      //Rest of links
}

Links.linkContains() {
   return Links.linkObject;
}
```

Import this file using `script` tag

```
<script src="links.js"></script>
```

Now in your main js file or any other file you can call this inside some function

```
function customFunction() {
  var getLinks = Links.linkContains() // will return the json array of links
}
```

Once you get the `getLinks` you can use `dot` or  `bracket` notation to get the value.

For example `getLinks.linkOne` will return `someLink`.

You can use this object to retrieve value anywhere in your application and when you will change the relevant value in link.js it will reflect everywhere